# Is there a way to switch to 5 ghz hotspot ap if there's no setting in the UI?

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, android-12

I'm using Android 12 crDroid 8.9 rooted on OnePlus 5. My phone has a broken 2.4 GHz wifi, it works very bad: disconnects, slow speed and low connectivity.

I want to switch my AP hotspot to 5 GHz, but there's no option in the UI.

Does anyone know if there is a way to force 5 GHz AP via adb or by changing some system files?